# How to negate all children in CSS?

Tags: css, css-selectors, negation

I need to select all `<div>`s on the page, except for all children of *a* `div` with an id of `do-not-select`.
My current selector is:

```
div:not(#do-not-select *)
```

However, it does not work because the `:not` operator does not allow complex selectors. Specifying all of the children manually

```
div:not(#child1):not(#child2):not(#child3)...
```

is not an option as there are too many of them.
How can I write such a selector with the current CSS3 limitations?

**Edit:** I can only use one selector (I can't have one selector to target all `div`s, and another target all children of a specific `div`, to negate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it like this:

```
div:not(#do-not-select) * { ... }
```

It selects all children of all DIVs except of those with ID  `#do-not-select`

```css
* {
  border: 1px solid red;
  padding: 3px;
}

div:not(#do-not-select) * {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</div>
<div id="do-not-select">
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
  <div>6</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to select not just the children, but the divs themselves too?

Comment: @Victor2748 That would be `div:not(#do-not-select), div:not(#do-not-select) * {...}`

Answer (score 2):

```css
article > div {
  border: 1px solid green;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}

article > div:not(#do-not-select) > div {
  height: 20px;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 5px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div id="do-not-select">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</article>
```